# OSGi WAB - it possible to use JSPs from another bundle/WAB

Tags: web-applications, osgi

I have some JSPs that I'd like to split out into another bundle/WAB and import into the main WAB for use in `<jsp:include>` tags.

Is this possible? Can WABs interact with the HttpService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OSGi enterprise spec WAB does not interact with HTTPService. The WABExtender handles the deployment aspects of the WAB (basically registers,... WAB with web-container ). I think this is because you can't fulfill all the requirements of a Web-application using the HTTPService (like registering a filter)

The Pax-web[1] follows a different approach. They define their own service called WebContainer. Extentsion to the HTTPService, WebContainer service can handle all web-app requirements. So Under the hood PAX-Web project registers servlets,filters,etc with the webContainer service by looking through the web.xml.

[1] http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web

hth